# How can I access from a service to a bean created in other service?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have two microservices in Spring, A and B. Service A creates a bean of a class called classA, and in service B I have a classB that needs classA in the constructor to build it. So I have in the constructor of class B an @Autowired annotation to inject the bean of classA, and also I have the import statement of classA from the other service.

I have used getBeanDefinitionNames() method in service A to know what beans have been created when I run it, and the bean that class B needs in the other service is created, but when I run service B I get an error that says that I cannot create instance of B because there is no bean of class A. I have put the dependency of A in the pom file of service B and it is like service B cannot use the context of A or they dont share the same context or I do not know the reason. Any idea about how can I solve this problem?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@Component` to Class A in the following way, which will add it to the spring context, and make sure it's package is falling within spring's component scan.

```
@Component
public Class A { ...}
```

Comment: I already have @Component in class A, and it is shown in console that this bean is created with the getBeanDefinitionNames() methods, I have the dependency to service A in the pom file of service B and in class B I have the import to the class of service A. 

If I use in class B @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.packageName") it works but because it creates an instance for each class of this specified package. But if I use this annotation, why I need to create a bean in the context supposed to be reached for the remaining services when service A runs?

Comment: Mixing concepts here. The scanning doesn't create an instance of each class of the scanned packages, it just tells spring "look for annotations here, you might have to do something with them". Only classes annotated with @Component, @ Service etc will be added to the context. However, if you annotate a class with @ Component but you don't scan the package it is in, spring won't "see" it and won't add it to the context, hence the injection will fail.